# Waiting for Firebase Auth to finish and then load the data to fragment

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase Authentication and I have implemented (along with UI) an authentication system to log in and register my users.

On my first fragment, I have a recycler view that loads some data from firestore database executing queries that needs the data from the current user (ID) and, since it's loading before the main activity for some reason, it crashes every single time because the user is null.

Inside the onCreateView of the Fragment class, I have tried with an if-else condition that forces the user to log in if it's null and won't call the methods that load data but after I have logged in the method only will be called when the fragment is reloaded manually again (when changing fragments) so the data being showed is not accurate.

Is there any way to change this and make the fragment wait until the registration is done?

(The code crashes when the method loadAllHousesId is called)

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at cat.itb.studenthousing.fragments.LandingPage.loadAllHousesId(LandingPage.java:61)
```

My code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    public static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> provider = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.AnonymousBuilder().build()

    );


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


                if (user == null) {
                    
                    startActivity(AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(provider)
                            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                            .build());

                } 
            }
        };


        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_main);

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment =
                (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment);
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);



    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }


}
```

Fragment:

```
public class LandingPage extends Fragment {

    public static FirebaseFirestore db;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private EditText maxPrice, minPrice;
    private Spinner areaSpinner;
    private Button searchButton;
    String area, minValue, maxValue;

    //this var will store all the houses that the user has already applied for
    private List<String> housesId;

    ArrayList<House> houseArrayList;

    AvailableHousesRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


    public void loadAllHousesId() {


        db.collection("applications")
                .whereEqualTo("studentId", firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            housesId.add(document.getString("houseId"));
                        }
                    }
                });

    }




    private void setUpFirebase() {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_page, container, false);


        housesId = new ArrayList<>();
        houseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHouses);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        
        setUpFirebase();
        //here is where my code crash
        loadAllHousesId();
        loadAllAvailableHousesFromFirebase();



        return v;
    }


}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I just edited the question and removed some unused methods, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you try to call `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` before it has finished initializing and it won't ever initialize during the initial activity/view creation phase.

What you need to do is wait for `onAuthStateChanged` to fire at least once with a valid signed in user and then load the house data or have a fallback value when a user isn't signed in.

In its simplest form, replace

```
//here is where my code crash
loadAllHousesId();
loadAllAvailableHousesFromFirebase();
```

with

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            loadAllHousesId();
            loadAllAvailableHousesFromFirebase();
        } else {
            clearAllHouses()
        }
    }
};
firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener)
```